# Conditional scheduling of task

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks

I need to schedule a task using java timer, which does the following:

- Send a request every 5 minutes (which receives a status as a response)
- if (status != end state), then query status every 10 seconds for the next 2 minutes until    it reaches end state. If it doesn't reach end state by the end of 2 minutes, sleep for 3 minutes and resend the request.
- After 3 failed attempts (checking status for 2 mins with 10s interval), if end state not reached, revert back to 5 minute check interval

Logic for sending request and querying status has been taken care of. I couldn't figure out scheduling the tasks at various intervals.

I know the run() method should remember the last state of the task so that it can re-schedule the task appropriately.

I'm fairly new to timers. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `Timer` use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). This is much more flexible.

First create an instance with however many threads you might need - for running tasks concurrently:

```
final ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(numThreads);
```

Now, to schedule a task to run at a specified interval, use the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method to schedule your task. Keep a pointer to the returned `Future`:

```
final Future<?> handle = service.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {}, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Where `() -> {}` is a Java 8 lambda for an empty `Runnable`. Obviously you can pass anything you want in here.

Now, you want to run that for an hour. Simply schedule another task that runs in an hour and cancels the previous one using the `handle`:

```
final Future<?> cancellationHandle = service.schedule(() -> handle.cancel(false), 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Again `() -> handle.cancel(false)` is a Java 8 lambda, this time it's a `Runnable` that calls `handle.cancel()`.

To be honest, however, this looks something like a busy waiting model. I would look into Java's `wait()/notify()` methods to get `Thread`s to wait for other processes to complete and be woken the instant that happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Boris! Using Timer is part of the requirement! Can you help me with the logic, using timers!